# Elixir / Ecto / Postgres Select multiple columns as one

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I just want do execute an Ecto query with an simple concatination of two or more columns.

I think the following elixir pseudo code already shows what I try to do:

```
customers = Customer.undeleted(
  from c in Customer,
  select: %{id: c.id, name: c.name <> " – " <> c.street},
  order_by: c.name
) |> Repo.all
```

It drives me crazy cuz in SQL it is easy like this: `...SELECT c.id, concat(c.name, ' - ', c,street) AS name`

Any ideas how to solve this with ecto querys ?

Comment: Dogbert's answer is the way to go but I believe for things of such small complexity, it may make sense to just do it on the application level

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot use `<>` in a select expression in Ecto. If you want to call `concat` like that, you can use `fragment`:

```
select: %{id: c.id, name: fragment("concat(?, ' - ', ?)", c.name, c.street)},
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Dogbert answer, you can clean up the code a bit by putting the SQL function fragment in a custom macro as described in the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1-defining-custom-functions-using-macros-and-fragment):

```
defmodule CustomSQLFunctions do
  defmacro concat(left, mid, right) do
    quote do
      fragment("concat(?, ?, ?)", unquote(left), unquote(mid), unquote(right))
    end
  end
end
```

Then import for use in query

```
import CustomSQLFunctions

customers = Customer.undeleted(
  from c in Customer,
  select: %{id: c.id, name: concat(c.name, ' - ', c.street)},
  order_by: c.name
) |> Repo.all
```